# smoothing out lines on ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to smooth out the line in ggplot. I tried using geom_smooth but that is giving me a fitted line instead. My code is below

```
#step 1 is to load the csv file
dataset_edited = read.csv("dsccurves.csv", header = TRUE)
str(dataset_edited)

#Check figure of all DSC curves
plt_dsc_1 = ggplot(dataset_edited, aes(x=gt, y=enthalpy, group = location, color = year)) +
 geom_point(size=0.25)+
 scale_x_continuous("Temperature (degree C)",limits = c(50,75), breaks = seq(50,75,1))+
 scale_y_continuous("Heat flow (W/g)",limits = c(-0.37,-0.18), breaks = 
 seq(-0.37,-0.18,0.02))+
 theme_classic()+
 labs(title = "A")+
 guides(guide_legend(title = "Year"))+ 
 theme(text = element_text(size=15))
plt_dsc_1
```

Currently the image I get looked like this
[image: Current image]

This is my
[data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12rLtROQIjem0iDDdbtdcBat38_ZCJhcz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you use `geom_line` instead of `geom_point`?

Answer (score 1):

As per comment you could use `geom_line` to have line rather than multiple points lineup on your graph, however with your data the plot is looking like this:
[image]

The reason is that it seems that there is duplicate values for one year at one location: 2016-17 at Davis
[image]

So you might need to clean the data before plotting

#### Code

Plot 1:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=gt, y=enthalpy, group = location, color = year)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_continuous("Temperature (degree C)",limits = c(50,75), breaks = seq(50,75,1))+
  scale_y_continuous("Heat flow (W/g)",limits = c(-0.37,-0.18), breaks = 
                       seq(-0.37,-0.18,0.02))+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(title = "A")+
  guides(guide_legend(title = "Year"))+ 
  theme(text = element_text(size=15))
```

Plot 2:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=gt, y=enthalpy, color = year)) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous("Temperature (degree C)",limits = c(50,75), breaks = seq(50,75,1))+
  scale_y_continuous("Heat flow (W/g)",limits = c(-0.37,-0.18), breaks = 
                       seq(-0.37,-0.18,0.02))+
  facet_grid(year~location)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing the repetitions, it hasn't fixed how the plot shows up with geom_line though.

Comment: It looks like you have multiple duplicate value in your dataframe with several `enthalpy` for a given group. `df %>% select(-enthalpy) %>%
  group_by(across(everything())) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  filter(n>1) %>% distinct()`. More than 12000 values are duplicate in your data frame.